# Impact of creating index after DML operation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created one table and loaded data. This data was loaded last year.

And today we have created a primary key. Will the primary key

uses row id for the the past records. Or should I rebuild index?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is a product specific question.)

Comment: A current structure of your table and some sample records would help.
As would knowing what type of database system you are using.

Comment: I am using oracle 12c

Comment: @ora1978 . . . When you create a primary key, it should apply to all rows in the table, not just new rows.

Comment: primary key will create index automatically. Will the index gets created for past data

Comment: @Dragonthoughts - I don't see it. How would a "current structure of table" and "some sample records" help with this specific question? I doubt they would. Don't dilute the importance of those observations (which are crucial for many questions asked on SO) by using them when they don't apply.

Answer (score 1):

> "primary key will create index automatically."

Yes. Unless there is an existing index on the primary key column(s) in which case Oracle will use that to enforce the key. There is no need to rebuild an existing index. This remains true even if the existing index is non-unique (Oracle's clever that way).

> "Will the index gets created for past data"

Yes **(*)**. The index applies to all the records in the table, not just ones add after the index is created.

**(*)** Strictly that should have been 'By default yes' as 12c introduced the concept of partial indexes for partitioned tables. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-256BA7EE-BF49-42DE-9B38-CD2480A73129.htm#VLDBG14102).